# windows 10 default save location

Tags: windows, save, default

I would like to force windows 10 every time I try to save a new documents, file, to not show me by default ths My Documents folder but rather a subfolder that I have named MyLibrary.
I tried already changing in registry the %USERPROFILE%\Documents to 
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MyLibrary
but the problem was that applications like outlook did not really started after that and I had to turn it back to the default to value.
Regards
Alex

Comment: This question probably belongs on our sister site https://superuser.com

Comment: yes you are right. My apologies on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As taken from here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-default-save-location-windows-10

Also here: http://windowsreport.com/set-default-save-location-windows-10/

> Open Start Menu > Settings > System settings.
>
> Next, click on Storage in the left pane.
>
> Scroll down a bit and find Save locations.
>
> Here you will see New documents will save to setting – and similar
> settings for Music, Pictures & Videos.
>
> Select the location from the drop-down menu.
>
> Thus you can set different Save locations for different types of
> files.